# Why am I forced to refresh to see the google map?

Tags: html

I am buliding a website and it has a google map in it, and i don't know why but it doesn't always show. I have to refresh a few times and then it shows.

Why does it not show in the first place?

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAvQSMMq5BnBhU3wg6d-mhuNXbcSdsN2Ls&callback=initMap"></script>

<div  class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid text-center bg-white mb-0">
     <div id="map" class=""></div>
</div>

<script>
function initMap() {
              var myLatLng = {lat: -34.604342, lng: -58.454327};

              var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapa'), {
                zoom: 15,
                center: myLatLng
              });

              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,
                title: 'Nuestro local'
              });
            }
    </script>
```

Comment: please share the html code

Comment: If you are using map with API you may be using one in X API. That means in every X time you will get that endpoint response (if you are lucky)

Comment: style="display:hidden;"

Comment: I shared the code, sorry, first question in here

Comment: Do you get any messages in the console when it *doesn't* work…?